# Remove item after max reached w/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, I am trying to clone table with 3 elements in it. After I make 3 clones I need to continue cloning but remove item **.val3**.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var $table = $(this).prev();
    $table.after($table.clone());
    e.preventDefault();

    var n = $(".val3").length;

    if (n > 3) {
        if (!$(".val3").hasClass("max3")) {
            $(".val3").remove();
        }
    } else {
        $(".val3").addClass("max3");
    }
});

<table border="1"> 
<tr> 
  <td>
  <div class="val1">val 1</div>
  <div class="val2">val 2</div>
  <div class="val3">val 3</div>
  </td> 
</tr> 
</table>
<a href="#">copy</a>
```

I decided that I'll add a class to the first 3 and then check if the class does not exist, remove the div. I think i got lost in my own logic...

Here's [jfiddle I put as a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uR7Aw/).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.splice` method to remove all `.val3` elements except for the first three ones.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var $table = $(this).prev();
    $table.after($table.clone());
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.val3').slice(3).remove()
});
```

If you want to every but the last three elements, use `.slice(0, length-3)`, as shown in the code below. **Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uR7Aw/1/**

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    var $table = $(this).prev();
    $table.after($table.clone());
    e.preventDefault();
    var length = $('.val3').length;
    if(length >= 3) $('.val3').slice(0, length - 3).remove();
});
```

### EDIT

Instead of removing the row after appending, you can also prevent more `.val3` rows from being added when 3+ rows already exist:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $table = $(this).prev();
    var $clone = $table.clone();

    var length = $('.val3').length;
    if(length >= 3) $('.val3', $clone).remove();
    //Equivalent to $clone.find('.val3').remove();

    $table.after($clone);
});
```

Comment: Does not have to be in a particular order, as long as max = 3. Thanks.

Comment: @santa To not confuse users, use either of the previously mentioned methods. Don't randomly remove rows from the table.